# Regex to extract all image URLs from HTML string not correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to extract all image URLs from an HTML string using regex `/<img.*?src="(.*?)"[^>]+>/g` in a function like this:

```
function getImages(string) {
    const imgRex = /<img.*?src="(.*?)"[^>]+>/g;
    const images = [];
    let img;
    while ((img = imgRex.exec(string))) {
        images.push(img[1]);
    }
    return images;
}
```

However, the results also contain non-image stuff, e.g.:

```
[
  'https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=900220307025564&ev=PageView&noscript=1',
  'https://cyclingmagazine.ca/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Peloton-Bike_Cam-1200x675.jpg',
  'https://cyclingmagazine.ca/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/ontario-creates-logo.png',
  'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"></div><div id=',
  'https://cyclingmagazine.ca/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/cycling-pop-up.jpg'
]
```

which breaks subsequent execution. I am by no means a regex expert (clearly), would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use regex for this. Use the [DOMParser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and its [parseFromString() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString).

```js
let str = "<img src='https://www.example.com'>";

let DOMParsing = new DOMParser()
let parsed = DOMParsing.parseFromString(str, "text/html")

// Now you can use querySelector to target the wanted element
// or querySelectorAll and a loop for multiple elements
let imgURL = parsed.querySelector("img").src

console.log(imgURL)
```

Comment: This doesn't extract urls, `<img src='data:image/gif;base...` would be included too

Comment: it extracts the `src` attribute value... While the is a `data:...` value in the question's code, the question was not specific to that. Anyway, the is no URL at all to be extracted from a `data` or `blob` url.

Comment: @KScandrett ... what makes you think `"data:image/gif;base ..."` was not a totally valid URL?

Comment: Whatever... It is extracted. That is my point. Then, do what you have to do with the extracted result.

Comment: @PeterSeliger fair point

Comment: @KScandrett ... Even more important is, that *Louys'* example demonstrates the advantage of making use of available parsers over self-knitted and/or third party  reg-expressions ... the former always is reliable without an own effort.

Comment: Thanks - took your advice, used jsdom to build a DOM from the HTML string and query all images instead.